# What's the columns updating order when several columns are updated?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-server-2016

I have simple table:

```
Col001
Col002
...
ColNNN
...
Col001_DateTimeModified
Col002_DateTimeModified
...
ColNNN_DateTimeModified
```

The `ColXXX` is holding value and the `ColNNN_DateTimeModified` is holding the corresponding date and time when the value was modified (inserted or updated).

When the value of one column is updated, all column values for the given row are used. I want to update the modification times columns, only if new the corresponding column is updated. So, I have:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Col001 = S.[Col001] 
   ,Col002 = S.[Col002]
   ,...
   ,Col001_DateTimeModified = IIF(Col001 = S.[Col001], Col001_DateTimeModified, GETUTCDATE())
   ,Col002_DateTimeModified = IIF(Col002 = S.[Col002], Col002_DateTimeModified, GETUTCDATE())
   ,...
FROM MyTable T
INNER JOIN NewData S
    ON T.[id] = S.[id]
```

Can I be sure, that when the row `Col001_DateTimeModified = IIF(Col001 = S.[Col001], Col001_DateTimeModified, GETUTCDATE())` is evaluated, the `Col001` is still holding its original value, not the value after `Col001 = S.[Col001]` row execution?

Comment: SQL Server is not updating a column at the time from your perspective. It's running the entire update statement as one statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The values are not updated serially, but all at once. Example:

```
create table #test (x int, y int, z int)

insert into #test values (1,2,3)

update #test
set y= x + z, z= iif(y=2,100,200)
where x=1

select * from #test

x   y   z
1   4   100
```

If the values were being updated in order, the value of z would be 200.

Comment: A simpler example would be `create table #test (x int, y int);insert into #test values (1,2);update #test set y= x, x=y; select * from #test;`

Comment: @MartinSmith I gave an example that was similar to the OP's own code.